How to create a VM that loads in a certain state for each user (for teaching customer support in high school)
I want to make an educational system where students are given a customer support ticket, and then are asked to log in on a VM to debug/find the error.
This requires the system to be loaded with the error/wrong configuration each time, and each student must have their own instance.
How would I set up Hyper-V to load an Ubuntu image with pre-configured errors every time?

You pay a consultant(s) to set something like this up.
